# ASP.NET 5 and the purpose of MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been working through the fundamental docs and various tutorials from the ASP.NET site such as [Getting Started with Knockout in ASP.NET 5](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/knockout.html)

I liked the Dependency injection and logging functionality that comes out the box as it were and I could imagine creating My data service layer registering it in the configure services section of the Startup class.  Obviously this would allow me to access any registered services from any future controller I create.

But having completed some of the tutorials and walkthroughs I discovered that if I opted to use knockout and jquery then I would create my viewModel on the page in javascript and Get/POST/PUT etc to my API directly from the client. The MVC controller for the page is never visited.  So why bother with MVC?

I've looked at examples where people call an action on the MVC controller which then calls through to the API but this seems a tad redundant.

I am relatively new to this technology coming from a XAML MVVM view point knockout is refreshingly familiar. So why would I bother with the MVC framework at all for a client application?
surely if I opt to use knockout/jquery then MVC is redundant?

Can anyone help clear up what I should be studying going forward?

Comment: Your question basically boils down to "why use a server side MVC framework when client side MV* frameworks are available." Right?

Comment: yes.  Basically I am trying to figure out a stack I can work with as I baby step myself into modern web development.  Should I just continue using MVC even though I have no immediate use for controller functionality, Given that I might learn a use for it later on?  I intend on build SPA applications, the things I would build will never be seen by a search engine, so perhaps I should just start with an empty site serve a primary page and let the JavaScript take over from there.

Comment: In that case I'm voting to close as primarily opinion based and/or too broad. You'll really just have to find the right mix that works for your application, and that's difficult for outsiders not familiar with what you're doing to be able to advise you on. It's a good question and one I ask myself when I start a new project, but I just don't think it can be answered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: yeah that sound reasonable @mason  I am just trying to get a feel for what others are doing with this respect.  For the time being I am going to go with keeping MVC in the loop (even though I'm not yet using the controllers for anything more than serving the page)  I may find out later whether I actually need that functionality or not as I learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You choose the solution that brings you the most benefits. If you implement your application purely in knockout on the client's side, building pages with knockout components, etc. you're free to go with WebAPI. There's nothing you'll miss from MVC.

However, in some cases you'll still like to mix it. For example you might prefer to use MVC's partials to organize code. You might include nice, cached page localization based on Razor custom Html Helper and therefore keeping js cleaner and lighter. You might go for out-of-box client's side validation of your models that MVC provides.

Some project may also still have lots of references to MVC and libraries built on top of it. There is not much you cannot do withouth ASP MVC those days, but it still has a lot to offer and the penalty of not using everything is small.

Anyway even if you skip the 'V' part, Models (or ViewModels) are still there, you don't want to sent your Data Entities view ajax.